# Add gradient color to a custom UIView

Tags: swift, uiview, layer, uibezierpath, cagradientlayer

I realized a custom UIView class to a realize a sort of trapeze; following code I had used to realize the class:

```
import UIKit
import ChameleonFramework

class PolygonalView: UIView
{
    override init(frame: CGRect)
    {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {

        guard let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

        context.beginPath()
        context.move(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.minY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.minX, y: rect.maxY))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: 171))
        context.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: rect.maxX, y: rect.minY))
        context.closePath()

        context.setFillColor(FlatSkyBlue().cgColor)
        context.fillPath()
    }
}
```

Then in my UIViewController I had create my view:

```
let pol = PolygonalView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.bounds.width, height: 196))
        pol.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear

        self.view.addSubview(pol)
```

[image]

I achieved my goal, yep! But a problem has arisen: if I set a gradient, this gradient cover all the rectangular frame of the view.
Following codes and image...

```
let gradientColor = CAGradientLayer()
        gradientColor.frame = pol.bounds
        gradientColor.colors = [FlatSkyBlue().cgColor, FlatSkyBlueDark().cgColor, FlatBlue().cgColor]
        gradientColor.startPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        gradientColor.endPoint = CGPoint(x: 1, y: 1)
        pol.layer.addSublayer(gradientColor)
```

[image]

Any solutions to adapt the gradient to the real shape of my View?

Comment: CALayers have a `mask` property that you can use to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `gradientColor` layer's `mask` property to `CAShapeLayer()` that has the correct shape filled with black

```
 let mask = CAShapeLayer()
 mask.frame = // to whatever size it should be
 mask.path = yourShapeBezierHERE.cgPath
 mask.fillColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
 gradientColor.mask = mask
```

Comment: Thanks a lot guy! I'm noob to layer, bezier, than also mask. I must set layer's mask in my customView class (PolygonalView)? Could you also send me some link to learn about masks and layers? thanks a lot.

Comment: I don't have a link other than the official Apple Docs

Comment: So, you could help me putting those line of codes?  I tried to set the mask in the UIViewController but I'm not able to recover path (I tried with pol.accessibilityPath and pol.layer.accessibilityPath but didn't work).

Comment: Just recreate a new one.  Optionally make a func that returns the right path and use it here and in your draw.